# wifi search for the devices connected to the same network i.e other than acces point(for android)

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

i want to make a modification to my project and right now the project status is.....
it is searches the available WiFi networks and shows the list with info of the network this works properly.Now i want to search and see the details of the devices connected to the network.
Is there any way to find these devices ?
Your comment will be useful for me, Thanks.

Comment: Use **AppFinder lib** [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281905/get-devices-connected-to-same-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically/44284242#44284242 ) Your Solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you like to discover a specific device ? Or you need the list of all connected devices? The second I don't think is possible.

**EDIT**

Discovering specific devices: 
Using `UDP Broadcast`. Some reference can be found [here](https://www.nakov.com/inetjava/lectures/part-1-sockets/InetJava-1.5-UDP-and-Multicast-Sockets.html)!

There are some protocols that are supported by some devices( routers, HDD, etc...), like [UPNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)!

If you develop a software on the device which you would like to discover you could create a `UDP` server listening on a specific port.
Your client will just send a `broadcast` message on that port and your `Server` will send a response with the information you need.
[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141221154045/http://systembash.com:80/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/) it is a simple example.

Comment: yes, i wanted to discover all.........but as you said it is not possible. so for to move further suggest me to search for specific device.Thanks.

Comment: Hi  Gyuri Majercsik, Thanks for the above link. I have tested it as an java application on eclipse and it is giving me response too. As i pass(hard core) a string message from client side it returns me a modified message. And now i am just confuse how to test it for android.

Comment: Hi Gyuri Majercsik , when i go through the comments on the page http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/ .... and i follow the procedure for this to work on android, i am not getting how to execute it on android. Provide me some hint. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Patric, look at this one: http://sionneau.net/en/projects/3-divers/11-jgroups-port-to-android

Answer (score 12):

You can loop over the IP ranges, and "ping" them.
It is not the best / fastest method (UDP is better) but, it works in many cases.
The sample code below returns the list of the IP addresses connected to the current network.

```
private int LoopCurrentIP = 0;

public ArrayList<InetAddress> getConnectedDevices(String YourPhoneIPAddress) {
    ArrayList<InetAddress> ret = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();

    LoopCurrentIP = 0;

    String IPAddress = "";
    String[] myIPArray = YourPhoneIPAddress.split("\\.");
    InetAddress currentPingAddr;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        try {

            // build the next IP address
            currentPingAddr = InetAddress.getByName(myIPArray[0] + "." +
                    myIPArray[1] + "." +
                    myIPArray[2] + "." +
                    Integer.toString(LoopCurrentIP));

            // 50ms Timeout for the "ping"
            if (currentPingAddr.isReachable(50)) {

                ret.add(currentPingAddr);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        LoopCurrentIP++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I like that one. Just funny how you loop from 0 to 255 and have an additional counter inside the loop running parallel.