# Network programming with Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

So I have never really done anything like this before so I wanted to get some advice on how to go about implementing it.

What I would like to do is to have a way to communicate with my raspberry pi via either 1) an Android Mobile Application that would connect directly to the Pi over the same network or 2) A web application hosted online that would have to connect to the pi

I want to control some social media like websites as well as youtube and pandora, etc from this application, so my initial thought was to run a Node server on the Pi, then just use an API on the Pi to give commands. The only thing is I have no idea how to connect programmatically to the Pi. I mean technically I could set the pi to a static IP and just hard code my app to use that static IP, but what if I want this to not be so hardcoded and instead use a dynamic IP on the Pi and have the App some how "scan" the network for the Pi.

Is this kind of thing possible for this kind of application?

Any help is welcoming

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing a similar work on pi. I have two suggestions for you.

1. Write some code in raspberry so when it is online, it will inform server with its communication address, more or less a p2p pattern. After that your android phone can connect to it
2. If you are sure they are in same network, you can do a network scan that is possible. [wifi search for the devices connected to the same network i.e other than acces point(for android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445928/wifi-search-for-the-devices-connected-to-the-same-network-i-e-other-than-acces-p)
   Some good ways are explained in this page. I prefer broadcasting method.

(You can download an app called Fing to see what kind of information you can get via network scan)

Answer (score 0):

There are several popular protocols for finding peers on the same network, usually based on multicasting. One of the most widely used is [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). Several Android implementations are available, for example [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/)

As for the second option "A web application hosted online that would have to connect to the pi" - you'll have to do it in the opposite direction - connect from your Pi to the online server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have IP assigned by dhcp you can use any free 'dynamic dns' solution and remember only the fqdn...

The quickest way (without any extra installation) of accessing your RPi is by ssh and run a command that will trigger something to your social media...