# Get the list of all the devices connected within same Network Android

Tags: android

In Android,

1. How to get the list of devices connected in same WiFi Network?
2. How to get the nearest devices from your smartphone connected with same     WiFi network?
3. Did frequency check is able to find the nearest device?

Comment: what you have to achieve this ?

Comment: get device info and connect to device.

Comment: i am now in research and developing stage , how am i able to show the code?

Comment: if u any suggestions ,its welcome

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386948/how-to-detect-all-the-devices-connected-in-a-wifi-network-from-android-app) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445928/wifi-search-for-the-devices-connected-to-the-same-network-i-e-other-than-acces-p) answer

Comment: i tried that but its not fetching those wi-fi connected details,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution for list of devices connected in same network,and i placed the code below

Call this method in onCreate -> getClientList(true, 200);

write this method in our class

```
  public ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables, int reachableTimeout) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> result = null;
    try {
        result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                String mac = splitted[3];
                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).isReachable(reachableTimeout);

                    if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                        result.add(new ClientScanResult(splitted[0], splitted[3], splitted[5], isReachable));
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

if any clarifications, please reply a message for this post,
THANKS

Comment: The file /proc/net/arp does not contain all devices connected to the same network. It is only a cache of recently connected devices. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035636/how-to-get-all-ip-address-of-systems-connected-to-same-wi-fi-network-in-android

Comment: @Narendran after getting the list of connections how to get connect ?

Comment: is it possible to get All Connected Device mac ID and LocalIP ?